# How can I add 2 integer values of 2 different integer keys inside a dictionary in python?

Tags: python

Hi have a program where I'm using a dictionary to create players, with stats being name , attack , defence, total. Is there a way where I can set total in the dictionary or will I have to add up attack and defence outside the dictionary then put it back inside?

```
Player1 = {
    "name":"Bob",
    "attack":7,
    "defence":5,
    "total":Player1["attack"]+Player1["defence"],
}
```

Comment: By writing `"total": 12` instead. What is the context of this? Do you want any change on attack to automatically be reflected on the dict? In that case you should not use a dict at all but a custom class with a computed property instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately what you're asking isn't do able as far as I'm aware... you'd be better using a class

like this:

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Bob"
        self.attack = 7
        self.defence = 5
        self.total = self.attack + self.defence

player = Player()
print(player.total)
```

What you've got to remember is you've not instantiated the dict when you declare it, so inside the `{}` you can't call `Player1` as it doesn't exist in the context yet.

By using classes you could also reuse the example above by doing something like:

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self, name, attack, defence):
        self.name = name
        self.attack = attack
        self.defence = defence
        self.total = self.attack + self.defence

player1 = Player(name="bob", attack=7, defence=5)
player2 = Player(name="bill", attack=10, defence=7)
print(player1.total)
print(player2.total)
```

EDIT: fixed typo

Answer (score 1):

You are currently trying to access `Player1` before creating it.

You could do:

```
Player1 = {
    "name":"Bob",
    "attack":7,
    "defence":5
}
Player1["total"] = Player1["attack"] + Player1["defence"]
```

However, this is not ideal, because you need to remember to adjust the `'total'` field whenever `'attack'` or `'defence'` change. It's better to compute the total value on the fly, since it is not an expensive computation.

This can be achieved by writing a `Player` class with a property `total`.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, attack, defence):
        self.name = name
        self.attack = attack
        self.defence = defence

    @property
    def total(self):
        return self.attack + self.defence
```

Demo:

```
>>> Player1 = Player('Bob', 1, 2)
>>> Player1.name, Player1.attack, Player1.defence, Player1.total
('Bob', 1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you don't want to compute value of the key total yourself. You can initialize it to `None` (Standard practice. Better than omitting it).

```
Player1 = {
    "name":"Bob",
    "attack":7,
    "defence":5,
    "total":None
}
```

Then update it's value later on.

```
Player1["total"] = Player1["attack"] + Player1["defence"]
```